# convert class components to functional components react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

as i am new in react native. i have no much knowledge of class component. i was stuck in code as class components are used in this code but i want to convert them into functional components. anyone please help me to convert this given code into functional component. this is a code of a swipeable card in react native all the given code in class component and use of constructor and this. i want to just convert it into functional component.

```
    //This is an example of Tinder like Swipeable Card//
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    //import react in our code.
    import {
    Platform, StyleSheet, View, Text,
    Dimensions, Animated, PanResponder,
    } from 'react-native';
    //import all the components we are going to use.
    const SCREEN_WIDTH = Dimensions.get('window').width;
    class SwipeableCard extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
    super();
    this.panResponder;
    this.state = {
        Xposition: new Animated.Value(0),
        RightText: false,
        LeftText: false,
    };
    this.Card_Opacity = new Animated.Value(1);

    this.panResponder = PanResponder.create({
        onStartShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => false,
        onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => true,
        onStartShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (evt, gestureState) => false,
        onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (evt, gestureState) => true,
        onPanResponderMove: (evt, gestureState) => {
            this.state.Xposition.setValue(gestureState.dx);
            if (gestureState.dx > SCREEN_WIDTH - 250) {
                this.setState({
                    RightText: true,
                    LeftText: false,
                });
            } else if (gestureState.dx < -SCREEN_WIDTH + 250) {
                this.setState({
                    LeftText: true,
                    RightText: false,
                });
            }
        },
        onPanResponderRelease: (evt, gestureState) => {
            if (
                gestureState.dx < SCREEN_WIDTH - 150 &&
                gestureState.dx > -SCREEN_WIDTH + 150
            ) {
                this.setState({
                    LeftText: false,
                    RightText: false,
                });
                Animated.spring(
                    this.state.Xposition,
                    {
                        toValue: 0,
                        speed: 5,
                        bounciness: 10,
                    },
                    { useNativeDriver: true }
                ).start();
            } else if (gestureState.dx > SCREEN_WIDTH - 150) {
                Animated.parallel(
                    [
                        Animated.timing(this.state.Xposition, {
                            toValue: SCREEN_WIDTH,
                            duration: 200,
                        }),
                        Animated.timing(this.Card_Opacity, {
                            toValue: 0,
                            duration: 200,
                        }),
                    ],
                    { useNativeDriver: true }
                ).start(() => {
                    this.setState({ LeftText: false, RightText: false }, () => {
                        this.props.removeCard();
                    });
                });
            } else if (gestureState.dx < -SCREEN_WIDTH + 150) {
                Animated.parallel(
                    [
                        Animated.timing(this.state.Xposition, {
                            toValue: -SCREEN_WIDTH,
                            duration: 200,
                        }),
                        Animated.timing(this.Card_Opacity, {
                            toValue: 0,
                            duration: 200,
                        }),
                    ],
                    { useNativeDriver: true }
                ).start(() => {
                    this.setState({ LeftText: false, RightText: false }, () => {
                        this.props.removeCard();
                    });
                });
            }
        },
    });
}
render() {
    const rotateCard = this.state.Xposition.interpolate({
        inputRange: [-200, 0, 200],
        outputRange: ['-20deg', '0deg', '20deg'],
    });
    return (
        <Animated.View
            {...this.panResponder.panHandlers}
            style={[
                styles.card_Style,
                {
                    backgroundColor: this.props.item.backgroundColor,
                    opacity: this.Card_Opacity,
                    transform: [
                        { translateX: this.state.Xposition },
                        { rotate: rotateCard },
                    ],
                },
            ]}>
            <Text style={styles.Card_Title}> {this.props.item.card_Title} </Text>
            {this.state.LeftText ? (
                <Text style={styles.Left_Text_Style}> Left Swipe </Text>
            ) : null}
            {this.state.RightText ? (
                <Text style={styles.Right_Text_Style}> Right Swipe </Text>
            ) : null}
        </Animated.View>
         );
     }
   }

    export default class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        Sample_Card_Array: [{
            id: '1', card_Title: 'Card 1', backgroundColor: '#FFC107',
        }, {
            id: '2', card_Title: 'Card 2', backgroundColor: '#ED2525',
        }, {
            id: '3', card_Title: 'Card 3', backgroundColor: '#E7088E',
        }, {
            id: '4', card_Title: 'Card 4', backgroundColor: '#00BCD4',
        }, {
            id: '5', card_Title: 'Card 5', backgroundColor: '#FFFB14',
        }],
        No_More_Card: false,
    };
}
componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
        Sample_Card_Array: this.state.Sample_Card_Array.reverse(),
    });
    if (this.state.Sample_Card_Array.length == 0) {
        this.setState({ No_More_Card: true });
    }
}
removeCard = id => {
    this.state.Sample_Card_Array.splice(
        this.state.Sample_Card_Array.findIndex(x => x.id == id),
        1
    );
    this.setState({ Sample_Card_Array: this.state.Sample_Card_Array }, () => {
        if (this.state.Sample_Card_Array.length == 0) {
            this.setState({ No_More_Card: true });
        }
    });
};
render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.MainContainer}>
            {this.state.Sample_Card_Array.map((item, key) => (
                <SwipeableCard
                    key={key}
                    item={item}
                    removeCard={this.removeCard.bind(this, item.id)}
                />
            ))}
            {this.state.No_More_Card ? (
                <Text style={{ fontSize: 22, color: '#000' }}>No Cards Found.</Text>
            ) : null}
        </View>
      );
     }
    }
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    MainContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    paddingTop: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 20 : 0,
    },
    card_Style: {
    width: '75%',
    height: '45%',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    position: 'absolute',
    borderRadius: 7,
    },
    Card_Title: {
    color: '#fff',
    fontSize: 24,
    },
    Left_Text_Style: {
    top: 22,
    right: 32,
    position: 'absolute',
    color: '#fff',
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    },
    Right_Text_Style: {
    top: 22,
    left: 32,
    position: 'absolute',
    color: '#fff',
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    },
    });
```

Comment: you need to use the stateHooks like `useState` and `useEffect` ... but honestly class based react is much more managable and less spaghetti like imho ... functional components dont really bring anything to the table (you can still useState and useEffect within classes if you want), from benchmarks i have seen online, classes also are faster to render

Comment: React documentation explicitly mention you cannot use hooks (useState, useEffect, etc.) in a class component.

Answer (score 0):

the part in the render method is what you return.

to create stateObjects in functional components you will need to use the `useState` method

```
const functionalComponent = (props)=>{//props are passed in via props arg...
    const defaultState = Xposition: new Animated.Value(0),
        RightText: false,
        LeftText: false
    }
    const [state,setState] = useState(defaultState);
    ... // more stuff
    return (
        <Animated.View
            {...this.panResponder.panHandlers}
            style={[
                styles.card_Style,
                {
                    backgroundColor: props.item.backgroundColor,
                    opacity: Card_Opacity,
                    transform: [
                        { translateX: state.Xposition },
                        { rotate: rotateCard },
                    ],
                },
            ]}>
            <Text style={styles.Card_Title}> {props.item.card_Title} </Text>
            {this.state.LeftText ? (
                <Text style={styles.Left_Text_Style}> Left Swipe </Text>
            ) : null}
            {this.state.RightText ? (
                <Text style={styles.Right_Text_Style}> Right Swipe </Text>
            ) : null}
        </Animated.View>
         );
}
```

you should really go watch some videos on useState, you can be much more granular

to set the state you will need to use the `setState` method returned from the `useState` call : `setState({..state,{XPosition:55})` or something ... you do the `...state` to include the old state values, as the state variable will be overwritten with exactly what you pass in... it wont "update" the existing state it will overwrite it

the next bit is hooking into the functionality in `componentDidMount` you can do this with `useEffect`

```
useEffect(()=>{ // this is setup
    // do the stuff from componentDidMount
    return ()=>{ 
       // any required teardown can be done here
    },[] //[] signifies only do this when component mounts... not every update 
);// end useEffect componentDidMount
```

again there is alot more to useEffect, if you want to do stuff when specific state or props are updated